# Bootstrap Layout not rendered for an allowed unauthorized view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, layout

> $this->layout = 'bootstrap'

The code above is written on my `index` function which was accessible even without login.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}

public function index() {
    $this->layout = 'bootstrap';
}
```

The code above does not work, I tested. (many times)

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->layout = 'bootstrap';
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}

public function index() {
}
```

The above code also does not work. The bootstrap layout is rendered fine when logging in, but when I log out and access it again, the view is rendered as basic HTML.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any error ? Is your layout existing ? If yes, is the path right ?

Comment: The view is working as expected when i log in, but when i log out and access the view, the design was gone, just pure html was showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I got it, it was the authentication for logging in that was keeping the path for bootstrap from being rendered.

Since I was accessing the view without logging in, I just have to move that specific path outside the authentication clause.